# How to convert .handlebars files to HTML during a prebuild?

Tags: handlebars.js

I want to write HTML files with 'includes'. Something like this

***home.hbs***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    {{_header}}
    ...
    {{_footer}}
</body>
</html>
```

Then, in the terminal I want to do something like this:

```
handlebars compile home.hbs -f home.html
```

This would result in a single file `home.html` with all the partials loaded.

It really seems like this shouldn't be all that difficult, but every example I have found seems to result in a JavaScript module. I don't want a JavaScript module. I want a simple HTML file.

is there a way to do this?

Comment: I can't believe that there is no easy way to do this. This is the closest thing i have found, and it uses gulp - which is definitely unecessary. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-compile-handlebars. This whole frontend thing seems completely, ridiculously obfuscated.

Comment: we use this: http://zetcode.com/javascript/mustache/